# Moderate Facebook Comments Plugin via API (programmatically)

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I have a website using Facebook Comments Plugin. It's being spammed every day and I want to filter spammy comments using my algorithms serverside but I can't see how I can hide a comment or ban a user for FB Comments Plugin programmatically. Am I missing it or is it impossible?